# Google Spreadsheet Appscript: how to copy and set value op an entire row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a multi-logger based on API data that gets refreshed every minute.
[image]

With my orginal code that worked for a single person, the online status (true = online and nothing = offline) would be copied to a new row every minute based on another trigger.

Since I added more names and more fomulas in row 2, I am trying to edit the script to copy the entire row 3 starting from Column B, as well as adding a timestamp in Column A. **The data comes from sheet1**

```
function logDataA2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const sourceCell = sheet.getRange(3,2,2,40); // yes there are 40 names
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  targetSheet.appendRow([new Date(), sourceCell.getValue()]);
}
```

For some reason with the above code, it seems to only still copy the data for the 1st person and adds indeed a new timestamp, but all the other people are ignored. How do I adapt my code to work properly, meaning it gets all 40 columns, logs this and still create a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Append row with new Date() at beginning**

```
function logDataA2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const srg = sh.getRange(3,2,1,40); // you had 2 rows
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let vs = srg.getValues().flat();
  vs.unshift(new  Date());//insert Date() at front
  tsh.appendRow(vs);
}
```

- [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [Array.unshiftt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

**Recommendations for moving more than one row**

While appendRow is adequate for a simple one line change it would be a mistake to extend it's use to multiple lines because the actual write time takes a lot of time and spreading it over a large array of data saves a lot of time pretty quickly.

Just an example of how to extend this idea for multiple rows\

```
function logDataA2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const srg = sh.getRange(3,2,4,40);//multiple rows
  const svs = srg.getValues().map(r => {
    let c = r.slice();
    c.unshift(new Date());
    return c;
  });
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```